# ng-pattern regex throwing error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-pattern

I am using ng-pattern to validate number(Comma seperated input field allowing only number). But it is throwing the following error in the console eventhough it is working fine. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

ERROR: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\d+$+\,/: Nothing to repeat
    at new RegExp ()

```js
barapp.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;


            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });


            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="money" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="Money" ng-model="money" ng-pattern="/^\d+$+\,/" required format="number">
```

Comment: Try remove `/`. For example  `ng-pattern="^\d+$+\,"`

Comment: Tried... Still throwing error  :(

Comment: You have some errors with regexp. What are you trying to achieve? Remove `$+` from regexp.

Comment: I have an input field which should accept only numbers and while entering the numbers it should auto seperate the digits with comma (currency like)

Comment: escape $ character

Comment: Well, i can't help with your task with auto separate the digits with comma. All i can say, that you can remove `$+` from regexp. Example `ng-pattern="/^\d+\,+/"`. It regexp will work without error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare barapp in the module. Try this before the line

```
var app = angular.module('barapp',[]);

barapp.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;


            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue)
            });


            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+|\.+]/g, '');
                elem.val($filter(attrs.format)(plainNumber));
                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Declaring I have done. I am facing issue with the regex only.